# ng-repeat with no parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

i'm using Jquery Accordion http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

The expected markup is as follows. Being that the `h3` are outside of any parent container how can I use ng-repeat to repeat this structure? I've tried wrapping in a div but that breaks the accordion functionality

```
<div id="accordion">

  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>

  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>

  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your angular controller/code?

Comment: Can you use a directive here which would be repeated? With the 'replace=true' thing?

Comment: Would switching to the [angular UI accordian](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) that already ties nicely with Angular be an option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can explicitly declare start and end points for your repeater rather than enclosing items in a wrapper. Try:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 ng-repeat-start="item in accordionItems">
        {{item.title}}
    </h3>
    <div ng-repeat-end>
        <p>{{item.text}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of angular is this in?

Comment: I think it arrived in 1.2, so I guess the caveat would be you'd require that as a minimum.